# ext.net direct method, call from external class method

Tags: c#, asp.net, ext.net

I have a method in a class like below:

```
public class ActionHelper
{
    [DirectMethod]
    public string DeleteComment()
    {
        ...
        return "Delete";
    }
}
```

and I want to call it from grid command like this:

```
<Command Handler="Ext.net.DirectMethod.request({url: '/Classes/ActionHelper/DeleteComment', cleanRequest: true}});" />
```

but it's not working! how can i do that??? I use ext.net 2.2 and .netframework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

look at this example
http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectMethods/ID_Mode/

it can be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Put a `[DirectMethod]` in your code behind wich calls that class and use 
`App.direct.<Method>();` instead

Comment: No, still not working! should I add something like [DirectMethod] for method to my class?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, you either define the method inside the Page, User Control or any Custom Control, or you define a static method inside the Page class.

Here is a quote defining direct methods from a [post](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?12613-CLOSED-Difference-between-DirectMethod-DirectEvent-Static-DirectMethod) in the Ext.net forums:

> - DirectMethod (none static, must be public): server side handler is
>     raised when you call special javascript method (basically, proxy
>     method is generated by Ext.Net toolkit). None static direct method can
>     be defined inside Page, User Control or any Custom Control. Please
>     note, if direct method is defined inside user control (master page
>     placeholders are user controls also) or custom control then ClientID
>     of that control will be added to proxy method 1
>     Ext.net.DirectMethods.ClientIDOfTheControl.DirectMethodName(); You can
>     use DirectMethodProxyID attribute for the class to define own alias or
>     completely remove ClientID prefix Really, none static direct method is
>     direct event. Single difference, that direct method has no relation
>     with any widget (and its events) and can be raised by developer from
>     javascript (as javascript method)
> - Static DirectMethod (must be public): similar ASP.NET PageMethods, can be defined inside Page class only. With static page method the
>     Page life cyle is not execued therefore access to ASP.NET control is
>     not possible but response time much better (depends from your method
>     logic only)